# Regex exclude white space from selection

Tags: regex

I was trying to search text contents inside a few html files using regex.

I have created a regex `((?<=>)[^<>]+?(?=([\s\r]*<)))` that is working fine but search result also includes white spaces only values and leading white spaces.

```html
<h1>test</h1>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered custom-table" width="100%" align="center" frame="box" bgcolor="white"
    id="dtGrid" style="background:#fff !important;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Type
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

The search result will have `test`,
               `Type`, and a few other results with white spaces only.
How can we remove white space only values and leading white spaces from search result?

Comment: Please specify what you want. And the expected result. The reqexp you provide is a solution to unknown problem.

Comment: Regex is not the optimal means for operations on html. What regex flavor you're using. eg PHP/pcre you could try something like [`>\s*\K[^\s><][^><]*?(?=\s*<)`](https://regex101.com/r/EH4llt/1/).

Comment: With non-PCRE regex flavours you would probably want to use a capturing group and refer to its content rather than the whole match, something like `>\s*([^<>]+?)[\s\r]*<` (but then again you shouldn't use regex to match HTML)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
(?<=>)\s*+([^<>]+?(?=(?:[\s\r]*<)))
```

You have a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/GWtNTV/1/).

The results will be at the *first capturing group*

This is what I changed from your original regex.

```
 (?<=>)\s*+([^<>]+?(?=(?:[\s\r]*<)))
^      ^   ^          ^
|      |   |           \__ Used a non-caturing group (just recommended)
|      |   |
|      |   \___ This is now the begin of the capturing group
|      |   
|      \___ Added whitespaces with possesive quantifier (cannot backtrack)
|
\__ Removed beginning of first capturing group
```

Finally, if you wanted not using capturing group, and use just matches instead, you may use this regex:

```
(?<=>)\s*+\K[^<>]+?(?=(?:[\s\r]*<))
```

It is similar to the previous one. The difference is that is uses `\K` to *forget* the current matching string.

You have a new demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/GWtNTV/3/).